# XmlReader blocks after first read from a NetworkStream

Tags: deserialization, xmlreader, networkstream

I am having problems deserializing data from a network stream. Once the socket is opened the first read statement is successful but a subsequent attempt to deserialize the data blocks without an error (although it will eventually timeout).

I have checked that the correct data is being sent and that it is correctly formed. To confirm this I tried the same code and same data but using a file stream. I don't get the same behavior - the deserialization step does not block.

I realize that file streams and network streams have some differences but I would have expected the behavior to be the same.

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(Server, Port);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);

MyData recievedData;
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData ));

while (reader.Read())
{
  if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.Name == "MyRoot")
  {
    // The following statement blocks
    recievedData= (MyData)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
  }
}
```

After some additional testing I noted that the deserialization step will resume correctly if I force the server to resend the same message. However the subseqent read statement will also work (picking up the duplicate message) and then block again on the deserialization step.

It might also be worth mentioning the message is a single element. Something like the following:

```
<MyRoot xmlns="http://www.mydomain.com/mydata" someattribute="123" />
```